# RemoteWebDriver InternetExplorer navigate().to() timeout?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, selenium, functional-testing, webdriver

i was running a test remotely on internet explorer, and when using navigate().to() selenium returns me this: "12:13:58.770 INFO - WebDriver remote server: Exception: The driver reported that the command timed out. There may be several reasons for this. Check that the destinationsite is in IE's 'Trusted Sites' (accessed from Tools->Internet Options in the 'Security' tab) If it is a trusted site, then the request may have taken more thana minute to finish."

i've done what's said. but when looking at the browsers the page is loaded, but still this message continues.

i've already tried as simon told me: "(16:32:54) simonstewart: ponto: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_The_does_not_work_well_on_Vista._How_do_I_get_it_to_work_as_e " but did not solve. could it be google analytics that on the background is getting data or something like that?

ps: i ran the test on firefox and it works well. i've tried on Windows 7 and Windows XP, and Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: runs on Java, some say that have issues related with administrator role execution, wtv. but if i can remove the java tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently this is an identified issue: 
[Issue 282: Command Timed Out Issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=282)